# Sum a column based on max date and unique range

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, sum, unique, maxifs

Basically, trying to figure out how I can Sum the totals column based on the latest/max date, by town, ie filtered by unique and the latest date for each row.

| Date | Town | Totals |
| --- | --- | --- |
| September 5 | Loerie | 9 |
| November 8 | Loerie | 4 |
| May 7 | Flower | 2 |
| February 2 | Holo | 8 |
| May 9 | Holo | 7 |
| July 23 | Flower | 3 |
| June 7 | Dump | 1 |
| March 3 | Tzaneen | 9 |
| September 2 | Tzaneen | 4 |
| April 3 | Coffee | 7 |

Able to unique sort the town list, and show the totals for each based on max date with =maxifs(C$2:C,B$2:B,F2,A$2:A,maxifs(A$2:A,B$2:B,F2))

Need to be able to sort and sum those results in a single function, but unsure how. Arrayformula?
Shared the example doc.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SSNJJOoz1-pxVH0ZoFFZqChhZxjqtRz5dfvyQu76ueI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(SORTN(SORT(A2:C, 2, 1, 1, 0), 9^9, 2, 2, 1), "select Col2,Col3")
```

with `total`:

```
={QUERY(SORTN(SORT(A2:C, 2, 1, 1, 0), 9^9, 2, 2, 1), "select Col2,Col3"); 
 "Total:", SUM(INDEX(SORTN(SORT(A2:C, 2, 1, 1, 0), 9^9, 2, 2, 1),,3))}
```

only `total`:

```
=SUM(INDEX(SORTN(SORT(A2:C, 2, 1, 1, 0), 9^9, 2, 2, 1),,3))
```

Comment: =SUM(INDEX(SORTN(SORT(A2:C, 2, 1, 1, 0), 9^9, 2, 2, 1),,3)) works great thanks, can adjust it to other columns as need be. Any idea how to ignore empty "total" entries and sum the last non blank one?

Comment: @Morgol not rly sure what are you after with "how to ignore empty "total" entries and sum the last non blank one?" can you expand on it a bit more?

Comment: There's several columns with their own totals, so the current function you provided works great overall for that. I'm trying to sum the column based on latest date IF that row isn't empty, else uses previous date. 

Explaining a bit stupidly here. 
1 Jan ExampleA

Comment: In the example sheet, "C List", currently it adds 0 for Loerie, the blank cell, since it's the latest date. Since that cell is blank I want to use the entry that's not blank, ie the previous date. So that total would be 5 not 4.

Comment: @Morgol try in E14: `=SUM(INDEX(SORTN(SORT(FILTER($A2:$E13, E2:E13<>0), 2, 1, 1, 0), 9^9, 2, 2, 1),,COLUMN()))`

Comment: Works perfectly thanks a lot. Just needed to change the COLUMN() to the correct column and shift the filter ranges up as necessary. Thanks again